# Repeating or clarifying proofs in cited papers

Tags: soft-question, research, publishing

Is it bad form to repeat proofs or arguments that exist already in cited papers (while making it clear this is not my own argument but from the cited paper)? Instead of just citing the argument... I find it more 'readable' if I rewrite the argument within my paper in my own words. Plus the original argument may be slightly unclear, and can be clarified.

Plus it makes the paper more self-contained.

Comment: I personally like when people do this, especially if it is an argument that they will then mimic later on, while say generalizing the result.  However I have also had the experience of getting some negative comments from referees about this, and have been asked to remove sections from papers that contain too much of this sort of thing before publication.

Comment: I think this question might be better suited for academia.stackexchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how long the proof is (longer is worse, for your question) and how much of an improvement you are making (more is better).